# Un-ordered (UL) list distribution - First set in vertical then horizontal

Tags: html, css, html-lists

By using following html

```
<ul>
<li>1.List</li>
<li>2.List</li>
<li>3.List</li>
<li>4.List</li>
<li>5.List</li>
<li>6.List</li>
<li>7.List</li>
<li>8.List</li>
<li>9.List</li>
<li>10.List</li>
<li>11.List</li>
<li>12.List</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Please help me to create this type of listing only using CSS. The listing is dynamic so I cannot add any other classes in between.

I have tried to create https://jsfiddle.net/u39m0hk8/2/
I need better CSS for creating the distribution.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I need the css for this...

Comment: ul {columns: 3} ? Based on the img.

Comment: So, you've done nothing or made no attempts at solving this problem yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with `column-count`

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding; 0;
  margin: 0;
  column-gap: 2px;
}
li {
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: white;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1.List</li>
  <li>2.List</li>
  <li>3.List</li>
  <li>4.List</li>
  <li>5.List</li>
  <li>6.List</li>
  <li>7.List</li>
  <li>8.List</li>
  <li>9.List</li>
  <li>10.List</li>
  <li>11.List</li>
  <li>12.List</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two obvious solutions, the first is to use CSS Columns:

```css
ul {
  /* Defines the number of columns the 
     content should occupy: */
  column-count: 3
}

li {
  /* Irrelevant, but I used generated content
     to display the list-item numbers: */
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

And the second is to use CSS Grid:

```css
ul {
  /* using CSS Grid layout: */
  display: grid;

  /* defining three columns ('3') each column being one
     equal fraction ('1fr') of the available space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

  /* setting a gap between each of the list-items: */
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).
- [CSS Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).